# The orbits of $1,2$ are$ \{1,2 \}$. How the calculation is done here?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

For the permutation group $G=\{(1234),(2134),(1243),(2143)\}$ on the set $ X=\{1,2,3,4\}$. The orbits of $1,2$ are$ \{1,2 \}$. How the calculation is done here?

I know that orbit of an element $x \in G$ is defined by $ G(x)=\{gx \in X| g \in G\}$, where $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

How do I multiply a permutation of $G$ by $1$ or $2$?

Comment: On the notation: It can't be cycle notation if $G$ is a group.  The element $(1234)$ needs to be the identity element.  I can't remember the name of this notation, but it's shorthand for $\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\end{array}\right)$ by just copying the second rows.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Indeed, i see parenthesis and my mind forms cycles. It is the inline form of the permutations. The i-th element represents where does the bijection goes. As an example: $(2134)$ is the function: 1 to 2, 2 to 1, 3 to 3, 4 to 4.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, I got it here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupOrbit.html. please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permutations in $G$ are functions $X \to X$.  Therefore the group action of $G$ on $X$ is naturally identified with function evaluation.

For instance, the element $(2134) \in G$ is the function $X \to X$ defined by $$(2134)(1) = 2, \qquad (2134)(2) = 1 \\ (2134)(3) = 3, \qquad (2134)(4) = 4$$

---

To evaluate the orbit of $1 \in X$ under the group action of $G$, just evaluate each of the permutations at $1$.  You'll find the result is either $1$ or $2,$ and since the set of orbits of a group action forms an equivalence class, the orbit of both $1$ and $2$ is $\{1,2\}$

---

**Note on notation:** This is *not* cycle notation -- it cannot be.  The question and [the referenced article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupOrbit.html) tell us that $G$ is a group, and if we were to force cycle notation on them, then $G$ is definitely not a group.  Rather, the notation $(a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_n)$ is an inline shorthand for the permutation of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ mapping $i \mapsto a_i$.

Comment: I think you[re making a mistake.  The cycle notationb means that $(1234)$ moves everything.  So $1\to2\to3\to4\to1$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster If you haven't read my comment about the notation following the question, please do so.  It can't be cycle notation.  In this notation, the element $(1234)$ refers to the identity element, mapping $1\mapsto 1$, $2\mapsto 2$, $3\mapsto 3$, $4\mapsto 4$

Comment: Ok.  Haven't seen that before